# JAVA: How to parse Integer numbers (delimited by a variable number of spaces) in a line of a text file

Tags: java, parsing, integer, line, text-files

I want to parse numbers in a line of a text file line by line. For example, imagine _ as a space

my text file content looks like:

```
___34_______45
_12___1000
____4______167
...
```

I think you got the idea. Each line may have variable number of spaces separating the numbers, meaning there is no pattern at all. The simplest solution could be read char by char and check if it is a number and go like that until the end of the number string and parse it. But there must be some other way.
How can I read this in Java automatically so that I can get in a certain datastructure say array

```
[34,45]
[12,1000]
[4,167]
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `java.util.Scanner`. It has the `nextInt()` method, which does exactly what you want. I think you'll have to put them into an array "by hand".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int v1 = in.nextInt(); //34
    int v2 = in.nextInt(); //45
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Just implemented it within my code. Fabulous, never used this scanner before. Cool thx!

Answer (score 4):

If you only need your numbers in a data structure, e.g. a flat array, then you can read the file with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and a simple loop. `Scanner` uses whitespace as the default delimiter, skipping multiple whitespaces.

Given `List ints`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file); // or pass an InputStream, String
while (scan.hasNext())
{
    ints.add(scan.nextInt());
    // ...
```

You'll need to handle exceptions on `Scanner.nextInt`.

But your proposed output data structure uses multiple arrays, one per line. You can read the file using `Scanner.nextLine()` to get individual lines as `String`. Then use `String.split` to split around whitespaces with a regex:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file); // or InputStream
String line;
String[] strs;    
while (scan.hasNextLine())
{
    line = scan.nextLine();

    // trim so that we get rid of leading whitespace, which will end
    //    up in strs as an empty string
    strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");

    // convert strs to ints
}
```

You could also use a second `Scanner` to tokenize each individual line in an inner loop. `Scanner` will discard any leading whitespace for you, so you can leave off the `trim`.

Comment: You can avoid the empty element I think by first doing a `trim()` on the string before splitting it: `strs = line.trim().split("\\s+")`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'll add the trim

Comment: I think, scanner.nextInt does this for me. However giving you the point for the regex \\s+

Comment: `Scanner.nextint` will consume all the integers in a single loop, but according to your proposed result, you also need to know when you cross newline boundaries

Answer (score 1):

Bum it old-school with `BufferedReader` and String's `split()` function:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] inputLine = line.split("\\s+");
        // do something with your input array
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // error logging
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
}
```

(If you're using Java 7, the `finally` block is unnecessary if you use the try-with-resources.)

This will change something like `______45___23` (where _ is whitespace) into an array `["45", "23"]`. If you need those as integers, it's quite trivial to write a function to convert the String array into an int array:

```
public int[] convert(String[] s) {
    int[] out = new int[s.length];
    for (int i=0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Scanner does the job for me. + for your finally block information for Java 7